# add a tag into the fasta sequence name

Tags: bash, awk, sed, bioinformatics, fasta

I need help.
I have a fasta file such as :

```
>YP_00698.1 hypothetical protein sp [Species 1]
MDMQFGYFTRNPSTKYPATLYPREVSCALYEDDNENTSLIPKSRHYHYTIQPPINYKKLTNVDRYKNFRL

>YP_0098.1 hypothetical protein sp [Species 2]
MDMQFGYFTRNPSTKYPATLYPREVSCALYEDDNENTSLIPKSRHYHYTIQPPINYKKLTNVDRYKNFRL

>YP_009378.1 hypothetical protein sp [Species 3]
MEDNTAEDIIKNHLLNTSNDDDDDADSLKKKKENIDDIVKESKNVNLFFISYIKAYNDLVLFLKQQEIVFINILHLNNLNLSIYNLLQKCYSTKDKYKFLPDNNKNLLQLILTLKKNVKFRLKRLKDK
```

And I'm looking for a bash method in order to add `"_CT"` just after the `>Seqnames`, so I should get :

```
>YP_00698.1_CT hypothetical protein sp [Species 1]
MDMQFGYFTRNPSTKYPATLYPREVSCALYEDDNENTSLIPKSRHYHYTIQPPINYKKLTNVDRYKNFRL

>YP_0098.1_CT hypothetical protein sp [Species 2]
MDMQFGYFTRNPSTKYPATLYPREVSCALYEDDNENTSLIPKSRHYHYTIQPPINYKKLTNVDRYKNFRL

>YP_009378.1_CT hypothetical protein sp [Species 3]
MEDNTAEDIIKNHLLNTSNDDDDDADSLKKKKENIDDIVKESKNVNLFFISYIKAYNDLVLFLKQQEIVFINILHLNNLNLSIYNLLQKCYSTKDKYKFLPDNNKNLLQLILTLKKNVKFRLKRLKDK
```

I tried :

```
sed 's/^\(>.*\)$/\1 _CT/' fastafile.fa
```

But I get the `"_CT"` at the end...

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be easily done with `awk`, could you please try following.

```
awk '/^>/{$1=$1"_CT"} 1' Input_file
```

Explanation: Adding explanation for above `awk` code.

```
awk '            ##Starting awk program here.
/^>/{            ##Checking condition if a line starts from > then do following.
  $1=$1"_CT"     ##Setting value of $1 to $1 and concatenating _CT to it too.
}                ##Closing BLOCK for this condition here.
1                ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited line.
' Input_file     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

`sed` solution:

```
sed '/^>/s/\([^ ]*\)\(.*\)/\1_CT\2/'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use `sed` like

```
sed 's/^>[^[:space:]]\{1,\}/&_CT/' fastafile.fa > newfastafile.fa
sed 's/^>[^ \t]\{1,\}/&_CT/' fastafile.fa > newfastafile.fa
sed -E 's/^>[^ \t]+/&_CT/' fastafile.fa > newfastafile.fa
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/hGckG9)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `>` - a `>` char
- `[^[:space:]]\{1,\}` - 1 or more chars other than whitespace. Note `\{1,0\}` can be written as `+` in a POSIX ERE pattern (enabled with `-E` or `-r` option)

The `&` in the replacement part stands for the whole match value.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace the first space on each line with `_CT`:

```
sed 's/ /_CT /' input_file.fasta
```

This should be sufficient since the FASTA sequence lines should not contain any spaces

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.*` can and will match the whole line, especially when your search pattern includes the `$` "end of line" anchor. Use something that can only match the sequence name instead, such as `[^ ]*` (a sequence of consecutive non-space characters) :

```
sed 's/^\(>[^ ]*\)/\1_CT/' fastafile.fa
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/qj7wdN).